# Fixed Point in Uniformly Convex Banach Space and Bounded Subset

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

The problem is
"Let $K$ be a bounded, closed, convex subset of a uniformly convex
Banach space $X$ and $F : K \rightarrow X$ be a nonexpansive map with $\inf{||x − F(x)|| : x \in K} =0$
Show that F has a fixed point in K."
Because infimum is zero,then there exist sequence $(x_n) \subset K$  such that $||x_n − F(x_n)|| \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. I want to show $(x_n)$ is cauchy sequence, but in the progress I get stuck. I dont know how to use uniformly convex.Help me, please!.

Comment: Where did you find this problem? It may be much harder than it looks... See Theorem 6.4.22 in ["Applied Nonlinear Functional Analysis"](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110532982/html?lang=en) by  N. Papageorgiou and P. Winkert. The proof is not elementary.